# How do i create a static text filter on a list webpart

Tags: 2010, list, web-part, filter

I would like to use a constant as a text filter on a SharePoint list webpart.

I can add a text filter and use it to filter the list successfully, but I don't want a control and I never want to change this value.

e.g. I was a webpart showing all items in a list with status = "complete"

Currently I am adding the text filter setting a default value and then making 0 height and 0 width but this still affects the layout and also seems like a strange way to do it.

I am sure I am missing something very simple here but anyways..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1- You can Edit the page from Browser: Ribbon -> Page -> Edit

2- Double click the ListView Web Part header: Ribbon -> [Edit Web Part Properties](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/edit-web-part-properties-in-sharepoint-2010.html)

3- In Web Part Properties: Edit current view

4- In Edit View page, [add filter to your field](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/filter-lists-with-views-in-sharepoint-2010.html)

5- Click save and you can see the filtered results!

Comment: So you are saying basically apply the filter to the view instead of the web part?

Comment: It's not _instead_ -- it's how this is done. The view of a list view web part is an integral part of the web part.

Comment: What is the web part rendering, its the view of a list.. So applying filter on view will actually filter data from the Web Part

Comment: if i have one view that shows a summary nicely it would be nice to be able to use that in various web parts, then apply a filter and give it a specific title like "outstanding items". that way changes to the view would be applied across many different web parts.  Though if you want the same filtering multiple places I could see the benefit in maintaining seperate views.